# How to open a powerpoint chart backend sheet in new instance

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am updating a powerpoint presentation using vba.
There are 30 charts in the ppt and I will be coping the data from some excel sheets to the backend excel sheets of the powerpoint charts. but each time I do it, I can see the new excel sheets getting opened in the taskbar. even though they don't display on the whole screen

```
 Set CExcel = New Excel.Application
CExcel.Visible = False
Set CWB2 = CExcel.Workbooks.Open(PPPres.Slides(lngSldNo).Shape(strChartName).Chart.ChartData.Workbook)
```

This is the code I am using, but it is giving me error that you can not open a file like this
can you tell me how the backend sheets of powerpoint charts can be opened in a new instance and without displaying the file and its tab also

Thanks in advance

Comment: first line of your code opens each time new instance of Excel application. You only need to add `CExcel.Visible = true` to see them all on your screen. However, I know it's not the issue. **From which application you run your code- Excel or PP?** What is the other part of your code- one some more lines from beginning and some lines coming next to what you presented now.

Comment: I am using Excel-VBA. I just want to open the a powerpoint chart backend excel sheet through a new instance so I can make it invisible.

Comment: what about the other portion of your code?

Answer (score 0):

The 1st argument to the `Workbooks.Open` method is a string containing the file path, e.g.

```
Sub Test()
Dim EAPP As Excel.Application, EWB As Excel.Workbook

    Set EAPP = New Excel.Application
    Set EWB = EAPP.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Myself\Desktop\MyFile.xlsx")

    Set EWB = Nothing
    Set EAPP = Nothing
End Sub
```

Not sure that is delivered by your argument. The `Application.Visible` property by default is `False`, so no need to explicitely set it. And I guess you have created a reference to the Excel Object Library to make use of the Excel objects in Powerpoint for early binding.

Comment: The same method I have used for opening some excel sheets, but for the powerpoint chart backend sheets there will be no location, so I cannot give a location

Answer (score 0):

**Logic:**

1. Get the shape which has the `Chart` object
2. Get your `Chart` object and then Get the `Chartdata`
3. Launch the chart and set your workbook and your Excel application objects

**Assumptions:**

For demonstration purpose I am assuming the following

1. `Slide1` in the presentation has one shape which is a chart
2. I have added both scenarios. i.e `Automating Excel from PowerPoint` and `Automating PowerPoint from Excel`

Is this what you are trying?

**Code: Automating Excel from PowerPoint**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    '~~> Excel Objects
    Dim oXlApp As Object, oXlWb As Object, oXlSheet As Object
    '~~~> Powerpoint objects
    Dim oPPChart As Chart
    Dim oPPChartData As ChartData

    '~~> Working with shape1
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
        If .HasChart Then
            Set oPPChart = .Chart
            Set oPPChartData = oPPChart.ChartData

            oPPChartData.Activate

            '~~> Set your Excel objects here
            Set oXlWb = oPPChartData.Workbook
            Set oXlApp = oXlWb.Parent

            oXlApp.Visible = False

            Debug.Print oXlApp.Name
            Debug.Print oXlWb.Name


            '
            '~~> Rest of your code
            '     
        End If
    End With

    '~~> Close And Cleanup
    oXlWb.Close False
    oXlApp.Quit

    Set oXlSheet = Nothing
    Set oXlWb = Nothing
    Set oXlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**CODE: Automating PowerPoint from Excel**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    '~~> Excel Objects
    Dim oXlApp As Application, oXlWb As Workbook, oXlSheet As Worksheet

    '~~~> Powerpoint objects
    Dim oPPApp As Object, oPPprsn As Object, oPPSlide As Object
    Dim oPPChart As Object, oPPChartData As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '~~> Establish a Popwerpoint application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oPPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oPPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> open relevant powerpoint file
    Set oPPprsn = oPPApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Presentation1.pptx")
    Set oPPSlide = oPPprsn.Slides(1)

    '~~> Working with shape1
    With oPPSlide.Shapes(1)
        If .HasChart Then
            Set oPPChart = .Chart
            Set oPPChartData = oPPChart.ChartData

            oPPChartData.Activate

            '~~> Set your Excel objects here
            Set oXlWb = oPPChartData.Workbook
            Set oXlApp = oXlWb.Parent

            '~~> This is required if powerpoint chartdata
            '~~> opens in the same instance of this excel
            oXlWb.Windows(1).Visible = False
            'oXlApp.Visible = False

            Debug.Print oXlApp.Name
            Debug.Print oXlWb.Name

            '
            '~~> Rest of your code
            '
        End If
    End With

    oXlWb.Windows(1).Visible = True

    '~~> Close And Cleanup
    oXlWb.Close False

    oPPprsn.Close
    oPPApp.Quit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set oPPChartData = Nothing
    Set oPPChart = Nothing
    Set oPPChartData = Nothing
    Set oPPSlide = Nothing
    Set oPPprsn = Nothing
    Set oPPApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I did try this method, but the workbook is still getting opened in the background. I can see the new excel file getting opened in the taskbar.( The excel tab will start flickering as soon as it starts to open the chart backend excel file)

Comment: Please refresh the page and try the 2nd method `Automating PowerPoint from Excel` posted.

Comment: The second code is just working fine to access the data, but still I am getting a new window been opened in the background